# Troubles with masking in Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, mask, snap.svg

I'm trying to use [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) to create a glyph icon (it will be animated later, but for now just the icon). It should look like this:

[image]

I've exported the paths for each facial feature. Then, using Snap, I've created a white circle and added each path to the element:

```
var snapFace = Snap('#face');

var faceCircle = snapFace.circle(17.075, 17.075, 17.075);
faceCircle.attr({
  fill: '#fff'
});

var faceLeftEye = snapFace.path('M34.4302501,33.1788512 C35.6480686,33.1788512 36.6363606,34.1675226 36.6363606,35.3819266 C36.6363606,36.6008833 35.6480686,37.5876578 34.4302501,37.5876578 C33.2162254,37.5876578 32.2313479,36.6008833 32.2313479,35.3819266 C32.2313479,34.1679019 33.2162254,33.1788512 34.4302501,33.1788512 L34.4302501,33.1788512 Z');
faceLeftEye.attr({
  transform: 'translate(-23.08, -22.81)',
  fill: '#fff'
});

var faceRightEye = snapFace.path('M34.4302501,33.1788512 C35.6480686,33.1788512 36.6363606,34.1675226 36.6363606,35.3819266 C36.6363606,36.6008833 35.6480686,37.5876578 34.4302501,37.5876578 C33.2162254,37.5876578 32.2313479,36.6008833 32.2313479,35.3819266 C32.2313479,34.1679019 33.2162254,33.1788512 34.4302501,33.1788512 L34.4302501,33.1788512 Z');
faceRightEye.attr({
  transform: 'translate(-11.08, -22.81)',
  fill: '#fff'
});

var faceMouth = snapFace.path('M40.2511192,53.2459206 C33.6627589,53.2459206 28.3195327,49.6857932 28.2884233,41.3393734 L52.208883,41.3393734 C52.183085,49.6857932 46.8387207,53.2459206 40.2511192,53.2459206 L40.2511192,53.2459206 Z');
faceMouth.attr({
  transform: 'translate(-23.08,-22.81)',
  fill: '#fff'
});
```

From there I grouped the three facial features and set them as the `mask` attribute on the circle:

```
var maskGroup = snapFace.group(faceLeftEye, faceRightEye, faceMouth);

faceCircle.attr({
  mask: maskGroup
});
```

I expected at this point for everything to come together. Unfortunately it looks like this:

[image]

I know the face's outer circle is in the right place as I can find it in the inspector; it's just masked. I can't figure out how to get the inverse to happen, where the facial features subtract from the outer circle.

If anyone has advice I'd really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should've looked harder. Found the answer here: [An SVG rectangle with multiple holes using Snap.svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053731/an-svg-rectangle-with-multiple-holes-using-snap-svg?rq=1) -- specifically this [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNqaNj).

Basically I had to add an additional circle to the mask, with a white fill, then set the facial feature fills to black.

```
var snapFace = Snap('#face');

var faceCircle = snapFace.circle(17.075, 17.075, 17.075);
faceCircle.attr({ fill: '#fff' });

var maskGroup = snapFace.group();
maskGroup.circle(17.075, 17.075, 17.075).attr({ fill: '#fff' });

var faceLeftEye = snapFace.path('M34.4302501,33.1788512 C35.6480686,33.1788512 36.6363606,34.1675226 36.6363606,35.3819266 C36.6363606,36.6008833 35.6480686,37.5876578 34.4302501,37.5876578 C33.2162254,37.5876578 32.2313479,36.6008833 32.2313479,35.3819266 C32.2313479,34.1679019 33.2162254,33.1788512 34.4302501,33.1788512 L34.4302501,33.1788512 Z');
faceLeftEye.attr({ transform: 'translate(-23.08, -22.81)', fill: '#000' });
maskGroup.append(faceLeftEye);

var faceRightEye = snapFace.path('M34.4302501,33.1788512 C35.6480686,33.1788512 36.6363606,34.1675226 36.6363606,35.3819266 C36.6363606,36.6008833 35.6480686,37.5876578 34.4302501,37.5876578 C33.2162254,37.5876578 32.2313479,36.6008833 32.2313479,35.3819266 C32.2313479,34.1679019 33.2162254,33.1788512 34.4302501,33.1788512 L34.4302501,33.1788512 Z');
faceRightEye.attr({ transform: 'translate(-11.08, -22.81)', fill: '#000' });
maskGroup.append(faceRightEye);

var faceMouth = snapFace.path('M40.2511192,53.2459206 C33.6627589,53.2459206 28.3195327,49.6857932 28.2884233,41.3393734 L52.208883,41.3393734 C52.183085,49.6857932 46.8387207,53.2459206 40.2511192,53.2459206 L40.2511192,53.2459206 Z');
faceMouth.attr({ transform: 'translate(-23.08,-22.81)', fill: '#000' });
maskGroup.append(faceMouth);

faceCircle.attr({ mask: maskGroup });
```